Optimizing a GeoTIFF with gdal_translate generate black areas
I have an collection of tile I want to add merge together into a GeoTIFF file.
Where the image is cut and should be transparent the value is 255 255 255.
After running gdal_translate these values are correct set to noData. But then a black area is present with value 0 0 0. I am not sure why or how i can correct it?
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_nodata "255 255 255" -co "COMPRESS=JPEG" -co "PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR" ^ -co "JPEG_QUALITY=75" -co BIGTIFF=YES -co "TILED=YES" -co "SPARSE_OK=TRUE" -co "BLOCKXSIZE=512" -co "BLOCKYSIZE=512" ^ processed\all_tifs.vrt processed\optimized.tif

